# Receiving error after setObfuscatedProfileId/setObfuscatedAccountId

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-pay, in-app-subscription

For my android app, I am setting up subscription/in-app purchases. Before launching the billing flow, I use setObfuscatedProfileId/setObfuscatedAccountId to specify a specific id for the purchase. However, when I do so, I receive the following error message/popup before the user attempts to make a payment:

```
Error
Something went wrong on our end. Please try again.
```

When I remove the setObfuscatedProfileId/setObfuscatedAccountId parameter, I do not get the error. I have also tried clearing data/cache from google play services and play store.

This is the code:

```
BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(sku)
                .setObfuscatedProfileId(profileId) // when this is removed, there is no error
                .build();
        BillingResult result = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this.activity, billingFlowParams);
```

In short, why would setObfuscatedProfileId/setObfuscatedAccountId cause an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, because it is not known what value `profileId` has.

Trying to set the same (unique) `profileId` twice likely would also not work out.

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setObfuscatedAccountId(java.lang.String)) states:

> If you pass this value, Google Play can use it to detect irregular activity, such as many devices making purchases on the same account in a short period of time. Do not use this field to store any Personally Identifiable Information (PII) such as emails in cleartext. *Attempting to store PII in this field will result in purchases being blocked.* Google Play recommends that you use either encryption or a one-way hash to generate an obfuscated identifier to send to Google Play.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to also add `setObfuscatedAccountId()` as well. Worked for me.